Trouble Registering Events in Substrate Tutorial's Frontend Transaction: Need Assistance
I'm a beginner following the Substrate tutorial from here. After successfully compiling both the Substrate node and frontend, I've encountered an issue.
Problem:
When I open the frontend and attempt to make a transaction, it seemingly sends money but fails to register any events. Unlike other tutorials where transactions are instantaneous, I'm facing this discrepancy.
Screenshot:
Here's a visual representation of the problem: 
Error Message:
Upon clicking the submit button, I receive the following error in the console:
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: u.tx[y][m] is not a function
    at M (TxButton.js:105:27)
    at async Object.onClick (TxButton.js:174:5)

Request:
I'm seeking guidance on identifying the root cause of this issue and resolving it. Any insights or suggestions on debugging steps or potential solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Open Transfer.js file
go on line number 84, you will see something like this
           <TxButton
            label="Submit"
            type="SIGNED-TX"
            setStatus={setStatus}
            attrs={{
              palletRpc: 'balances',
              callable: 'transfer',
              inputParams: [addressTo, amount],
              paramFields: [true, true],
            }}
          />


Change it to
           <TxButton
            label="Submit"
            type="SIGNED-TX"
            setStatus={setStatus}
            attrs={{
              palletRpc: 'balances',
              callable: 'transferAllowDeath',
              inputParams: [addressTo, amount],
              paramFields: [true, true],
            }}
          />

